# Passing String Arrays to Functions?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to pass the array people to the function getInformation and have it so stuff (eventually it will ask for the names of people and their salaries but I can't seem to get the function to take the array as a parameter?

```
using System;

class SalesPeeps {

    string[] people = new string[8];
    double[] salaries = new double[8];

    static void Main() {

        getInformation(people);

    }

    static void getInformation(string[] arr) {

        int i = 0;

        do {

            Console.WriteLine("Please input a the sales person's last name.");
            i++;

        } while (i < people.Length);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't seem to get the function to take the array as a parameter?"

Comment: Surely you're getting an error message from the compiler, which you can in turn search on Google.

Comment: Do you want the user to type 8 persons? Or where should the users input go?

Comment: David, that is not at all helpful. I searched Google before posting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `string[] people = new string[8];` 
is a field - not local variable. so when you say people - you are actually mean this.people but in static method there is no this. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

2) getInformation method use **arr** array as a parameter but do not reference to it. You can use people and make it static this will also fix problem from point 1.

I think this can be corrected this way:

```
class SalesPeeps
{

    static string[] people = new string[8];
    static double[] salaries = new double[8];

    static void Main()
    {
        getInformation();
    }

    static void getInformation()
    {
        int i = 0;
        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please input a the sales person's last name.");
            i++;

        } while (i < people.Length);

    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst your answer is formally correct - and more or less identic to the others - it probably won´t help OP much. To solve his *actual* problem however, there´s not enough information on what that problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access non-static field `people` from static method `Main`. Change its declaration to:

```
static string[] people = new string[8];
```

Comment: Whilst your answer is formally correct - and more or less identic to the others - it probably won´t help OP much. To solve his *actual* problem however, there´s not enough information on what that problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your variables are class members, which means they are the variables of the objects you can create from the class SalesPeeps.

Your method getInformation() is a static method and therefore only accepts static inputs.

A fix for this would be to make both of your variables static. Read more [here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-static).

Either way, you should be getting a error message from the compiler and this question should not be necessary as there are plenty of resources on this topic. Just check your compiler errors in your IDE and google them.

Comment: Whilst your answer is formally correct - and more or less identic to the others - it probably won´t help OP much. To solve his *actual* problem however, there´s not enough information on what that problem is.

Comment: @HimBromBeere There are several parts why OPs code wont work. But I figured he is a beginner and he should learn how to do it. Therefore I concentrated on answering the question " but I can't seem to get the function to take the array as a parameter?". The other problems he will be running into after fixing the first should be solved by himself with further research.